# SearchBar reappear after unwind push segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

I'm using this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSLog(@"searchbar hide");
    self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 44);
}
```

to hide `SearchBar` in `TableView`. It works perfectly.

**Here the problem:**
TableView's rows have push segues to a second scene. When the app cames back from push segue, `SearchBar` appears with rough animation. I want that it remans hidden just like Notes.app.

What I tried and didn't work:

- call the same method in `viewDidUnload` of the second scene
- call the same method in `viewWillAppear` of the main scene
- make an unwind segue called by a custom Back button (but this brings another problem, I want to maintain the typical < arrow...)

Is there a SIMPLE way to achieve this?

**EDIT:**
I debugged that what causes this is `SecondViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;` in `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender` method in main scene. If I comment this line the `SearchBar` doesn't appear, the problem now is that i have an unwanted `BottomBar` in my secondary scene.

As (almost) always happens, problem is shifted...

Answer (score 0):

Set tableview's contentOffset in viewWillAppear which will be called every time when the view is about to reappear in compare to viewDidLoad, which will get called only once during the lifetime of the view controller.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    CGRect newBounds = self.tableView.bounds;
    newBounds.origin.y = newBounds.origin.y + searchBar.bounds.size.height;
    self.tableView.bounds = newBounds;
}
```

here searchBar should be replaced by your's search bar

Comment: Did you call [self.tableView reloadData] afterwards?

Comment: Nope, I call it in `viewDidLoad`, but before `self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 44);`

Comment: refer the answer again, I have changed it

Comment: Same problem, this also messes up another unwind from a modal segue of a third scene which works perfectly with the setup in my first post.

Comment: Is search bar part of tableview?